# 'Shop By ' feature on Search page magento1.6

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

I want to show the 'shop by' feature only in search result page and tagged search page. I am using 2Column-left layout. I edited the tag.xml like

```
<reference name="left">
         <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>

</reference>
```

But it shows everywhere !! How can i customize this only for search result and tagged search ?

Comment: what tags is the above inside? Have you told it to only show in the search pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put this inside the correct tags? For example:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Have you also removed it from where ever else it appears? *e.g.* inside `catalog.xml`? Or with something like

```
<remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
```

What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

in catalog.xml and catalogsearch.xml, remove directive like bellow should fix:

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

You must clear magento cache to make your edit effect.